# Nice looking MFC listbox

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2005

I am looking an extended MFC listbox able to manage
- icon and text
- nice selection (vista style)

Do you know a such component ?

Answer (score 1):

[CListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in list/report mode could also include icon and text.

Comment: Yes, generally uses 'items' to represent data (entities) within the list and indeed you can add bitmaps to the item

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, the [bcgcontrolbar](http://www.bcgsoft.com/bcgcontrolbarpro.htm) library was [incorporated into MFC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/04/07/mfc-update-powered-by-bcgsoft.aspx) as a "feature pack".

I don't know if it supports listboxes with embedded images, but it will at least give you a nicer looking listbox with more features than the one in "old" MFC.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984191.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I am using the 2005 version of VS which does not have the Feature pack